# Вывод только уникальных записей

Tags: postgresql

Имеется таблица:

```
id  |org|value|
----|---|-----|
1030|  1| 1029|
1033|  1| 1032|
1039|  1| 1029|
```

Необходимо вывести только уникальные записи по столбцу `value`. Если `value` у записей повторяется, выводить последнюю.

Можно ли это сделать без использования `distinct on`?

Comment: *Если value у записей повторяется, выводить последнюю.* Последнюю по какому признаку, при какой сортировке? "физический" порядок не подойдёт - его не существует.

Comment: @Akina сортировка по убыванию

Comment: По убыванию. Повторяющихся значений `value`. Ага...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог следующий запрос:

```
SELECT id, value FROM
  (SELECT id, value,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     (PARTITION BY (value) ORDER BY id DESC) rn
   FROM db.v4table
   WHERE org=:org 
  ) tmp WHERE rn = 1;
```